# Desktop app to create event through a facebook page

Tags: c#, facebook, events, desktop-application

I have a facebook fanpage and I am trying to make a desktop application which can create events through this fanpage, however I'm having trouble understanding how the story goes with acces tokens, id, user permissions... If I am not mistaken once I have the accesstoken I can create an event using the facebookSDK from codeplex and the following function:

```
public string CreateEvent(string accessToken)
        {
            FacebookClient facebookClient = new FacebookClient(accessToken);
            Dictionary<string, object> createEventParameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            createEventParameters.Add("name", "My birthday party )");
            createEventParameters.Add("start_time", DateTime.Now.AddDays(2).ToUniversalTime().ToString());
            createEventParameters.Add("end_time", DateTime.Now.AddDays(2).AddHours(4).ToUniversalTime().ToString());
            createEventParameters.Add("owner", "Balaji Birajdar");
            createEventParameters.Add("description", " ( a long description can be used here..)");

            //Add the "venue" details
            JsonObject venueParameters = new JsonObject();
            venueParameters.Add("street", "dggdfgg");
            venueParameters.Add("city", "gdfgf");
            venueParameters.Add("state", "gfgdfgfg");
            venueParameters.Add("zip", "gfdgdfg");
            venueParameters.Add("country", "gfdgfg");
            venueParameters.Add("latitude", "100.0");
            venueParameters.Add("longitude", "100.0");
            createEventParameters.Add("venue", venueParameters);

            createEventParameters.Add("privacy", "OPEN");
            createEventParameters.Add("location", "fhdhdfghgh");

            Add the event logo image
            FacebookMediaObject logo = new FacebookMediaObject()
            {
                ContentType = "image/jpeg",
                FileName = @"C:\logo.jpg"
            };
            logo.SetValue(File.ReadAllBytes(logo.FileName));
            createEventParameters["@file.jpg"] = logo;

            JsonObject resul = facebookClient.Post("/me/events", createEventParameters) as JsonObject;
            return resul["id"].ToString();
        }
```

Do I always need an application to do this?

I have a test application and I can get an access token from it using:

```
public string getToken(string strURL)
        {
            string strURL = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=149585851811979&client_secret=blablablablabalalbal&grant_type=client_credentials";

            Uri Uri = new Uri(strURL);
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(Uri);
            HttpWebResponse HWResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(HWResponse.GetResponseStream());
            string token = sr.ReadToEnd();
            sr.Close();
            token = token.Replace("access_token=", "");
            return token;
        }
```

I tried it like this but it obviously didn't work.

So my questions:

Do I always need an application? If yes, how do i connect it to my existing fan page?
Where do I set my user permissions? And how do I then login with the user?

I just think the documentation is a bit vague :s Sorry if my questions are stupid.

Any help/pseudocode is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I am using BatchFB to create events in an App Engine app, it works for me, here is the code

```
  // Some Date math that is from my App, but I am using Joda DateTime for output
  // formatting.. I have found that if the start_time is malformed by FB standards it will 
  // to create an event, and give you an eventid, but the event never really gets created.
  long    hour = { your data }
  DateTime start_time = new DateTime(d).plusHours((int)hour);
  String stime = start_time.toString(ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime());

  Batcher batcher = new FacebookBatcher(token);
  Later<NewFeedItem> event = batcher.post(
      "/events", NewFeedItem.class,
      new Param("name", edata.getStringProperty(EventData.Schema.Name)),
      new Param("start_time", stime )
  );
  long eventid = event.get().id;
```

I generate token on the client side with FBJS, and pass it to the server.

NewFeedItem is just a class defining an long variable, see batchFB's site..

With that said, I am thinking of switching to RestFB because I can't get BatchFB to support binary parameters with trying to post images. Also RestFB is documented better.. They seem to be related projects and refer to each other often.

I am not adding in Venue data yet, but I have read that for the GraphAPI to work, they need to be top level parameters. i.e. add in street, city, state at the same level as location and privacy..
When you try to read the event it will come in the venue parameter, but it needs to be top level when creating.. Also fallback to just using name and start_time, the only required parameters and add to that once it's working.

-John Gentilin